# Google YouTubeService playlistItems returning non-existent cancelled On Air Hangout items

Tags: youtube, google-hangouts

I am using the standard/sample Google API code for listing the YouTube videos from a channel:

```
$channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels("contentDetails", array(
  "mine" => "true",
));

foreach ($channelsResponse["items"] as $channel) {

    $uploadsListId = $channel["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"];

    $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems("snippet", array(
        "playlistId" => $uploadsListId,
        "maxResults" => 50
    ));

    echo "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";

    foreach ($playlistItemsResponse["items"] as $playlistItem) {

        echo $playlistItem["snippet"]["title"] . " (" . $playlistItem["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"] . ")<br>";
        echo "<img src=" . $playlistItem["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"] . "><br>";
        echo "<br><br>";

    }

    echo "</ul>";
}
```

However, the list it comes back with is filled with TONS of On Air Hangout events, which I had initiated, but never clicked the "Start Broadcast" button which would have caused them to be saved/archived into my YouTube account.  It's almost like, cancelling an "On Air" Hangout before your start the broadcast creates these ghost playlistItems... How can I detect them (and filter them from the list returned by the API call that is displayed?)

Comment: No one using On Air Hangouts yet? ...or perhaps just not with the YouTube API as well?

Comment: Anyone? Hard to believe I have stumped the whole community on this one...